# How to write ProcessStartInfo to text file for Linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, process

I am using ProcessStartInfo to execute a linux shell script (".sh" file) from .net. I am able to copy the script content to a text file in the Windows environment, but for Linux this is not working. Instead of writing the process info it is writing the file info.

```
        protected async Task StartProcess()
        {
            try
            {
                //string txtFileName = TextFilePath + @"\" + "Info.txt";
                //File.CreateText(txtFileName);

                if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
                { 
                    SHFilePath = SHFilePath + @" &>> " + TextFilePath;
                    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(SHFilePath);
                    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                    {
                        CreateNoWindow = true,
                        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                        RedirectStandardError = true,
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                        FileName = "/bin/bash",
                        WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                        Arguments = fileInfo.FullName,
                        WorkingDirectory = WorkingDirectoryPath,
                    };

                    using Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);

                    process.WaitForExit();
                    process.Dispose();
                }
                else
                {
                    string path = @"E:\Backup\Segregation\BatchFilesTest";

                    string batFileName1 = path + @"\" + Guid.NewGuid() + ".bat";
                    string batFileName2 = "";
                    ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + batFileName2);
                    processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                    processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
                    processStartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\PBBI CCM\Vault\server";

                    Process p = new Process();
                    p.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
                    p.Start();
                    p.WaitForExit();
                }

                await Task.Delay(10);
            }
           catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(ex, "Error");
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Instead of writing the process info it is writing the file info."?

Comment: @Efrain I mean I am calling .sh file. In .sh file contain commands. that commands will execute another process. The program needs to copy that output to a text file, not .sh file commands.

Comment: Have you tried adding the TextFilePath only further down in the ProcessStartInfo Arguments property? `Arguments = fileInfo.FullName + $">> {TextFilePath}"` ... passing it into the FileInfo(..) constructor propably throws away the ">>" part (maybe use the debugger to inspect fileInfo.FullName at runtime)

Answer (score 0):

I belive you may be running in escaping and parameter handling issues here, i suggest you try:

```
SHFilePath = $"-c '{SHFilePath} &>> {TextFilePath}'"
```